# EWS Search for Fields like Company or Street in Global Address List

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I try to write a Webservice that can access to my exchange-server and search for names, companys and cities. At the moment i get the names like this:

```
ExchangeServiceBinding esb = new ExchangeServiceBinding();
esb.UseDefaultCredentials  = true;

// Create the ResolveNamesType and set
// the unresolved entry.
ResolveNamesType rnType = new ResolveNamesType();
rnType.ReturnFullContactData = true;
rnType.UnresolvedEntry = "searchname";

// Resolve names.
ResolveNamesResponseType resolveNamesResponse
= esb.ResolveNames(rnType);
ArrayOfResponseMessagesType responses
= resolveNamesResponse.ResponseMessages;

// Check the result.
if (responses.Items.Length > 0 && responses.Items[0].ResponseClass != ResponseClassType.Error)
{
    ResolveNamesResponseMessageType responseMessage = responses.Items[0] as
  ResolveNamesResponseMessageType;

    // Display the resolution information.
    ResolutionType[] resolutions = responseMessage.ResolutionSet.Resolution;
    foreach (ResolutionType resolution in resolutions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
    "Name: " +
    resolution.Contact.DisplayName
    );
        Console.WriteLine(
    "EmailAddress: " +
    resolution.Mailbox.EmailAddress
    );

        if (resolution.Contact.PhoneNumbers != null)
        {
            foreach (
      PhoneNumberDictionaryEntryType phone
      in resolution.Contact.PhoneNumbers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
        phone.Key.ToString() +
        " : " +
        phone.Value
        );
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(
    "Office location:" +
    resolution.Contact.OfficeLocation
    );
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
}
```

But anybody know how i can serach for Propertys like Company and Street?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EWS only has limited Directory operations if your using OnPrem Exchange then the easiest way to do this is just use LDAP and lookup Active Directory directly. The resolveName operation is meant to be used to resolve a partial number and doesn't work with any other properties. If you have Exchange 2013 then there is the FindPeople operation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj191039(v=exchg.150).aspx which supports using a QueryString which should work if those properties are indexed. eg

```
        EWSProxy.FindPeopleType fpType = new EWSProxy.FindPeopleType();
        EWSProxy.IndexedPageViewType indexPageView = new EWSProxy.IndexedPageViewType();
        indexPageView.BasePoint = EWSProxy.IndexBasePointType.Beginning;
        indexPageView.Offset = 0;
        indexPageView.MaxEntriesReturned = 100;
        indexPageView.MaxEntriesReturnedSpecified = true;
        fpType.IndexedPageItemView = indexPageView;


        fpType.ParentFolderId = new EWSProxy.TargetFolderIdType();
        EWSProxy.DistinguishedFolderIdType Gal = new EWSProxy.DistinguishedFolderIdType();
        Gal.Id = EWSProxy.DistinguishedFolderIdNameType.directory;
        fpType.QueryString = "Office";
        fpType.ParentFolderId.Item = Gal;
        EWSProxy.FindPeopleResponseMessageType fpm = null;
        do
        {
            fpm = esb.FindPeople(fpType);
            if (fpm.ResponseClass == EWSProxy.ResponseClassType.Success)
            {
                foreach (EWSProxy.PersonaType PsCnt in fpm.People)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(PsCnt.EmailAddress.EmailAddress);
                }
                indexPageView.Offset += fpm.People.Length;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Error");
            }
        } while (fpm.TotalNumberOfPeopleInView > indexPageView.Offset);
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: thx..this works for me..but do you know how i can specify the querystring to search for things?

Comment: FindPeople is what OWA use but it just uses it as a FreeText field eg if you wanted to find people in the New York office just use a Query String "New York" and then filter the results. It should also be possible to use AQS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj191457(v=exchg.150).aspx